# Filling the area between three curves with the command Filling

Tags: filling, area

[image]

Hi. I want to filling the are between the curves x^2, x and -x+1 from x=0 to x=a:=-1/2 + sqrt(5)/2. How can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code in text form.

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[{x^2, x, -x + 1, Min[x, 1 - x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, None}, 
 Filling -> {4 -> {{1}, {None, Automatic}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[{x^2, x, -x + 1}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, {Automatic, None}}}]
```

[image]

You can replace Automatic with whatever directive you want.

### Update

Missed that the desire was to highlight the area between all three. Here's one approach:

```
Plot[{x^2, x, -x + 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, {Automatic, None}}, 2 -> {{3}, {White, None}}}]
```

[image]

It's a bit hacky, in that it assumes the background to be white, but it avoids introducing extra functions.

Comment: But I don't want the top to be painted. I only want the part enclosed by the three curves.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the little `x`. I read it as `between the curves x^2 and -x+1`. Others have already posted answers.

Comment: I posted a slightly different way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

An alternative to using [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
  Tooltip[y < x && y < 1 - x && y > x^2 && 0 < x < 1],
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "y"})],
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Tooltip /@ {x^2, x, -x + 1}], {x, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.5, .8}]]]
```

[image]